# Not all .htaccess files are read

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have used MAMP and Ubuntu server for years but have recently tried to use the built-in Apache Server on Mac OS X 10.7.5. My problem is some of my .htaccess files are being read and some are not. I have 2 sites and here are their vhost settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.rob
    DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/localSites/site1/public/
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.rob
     DocumentRoot /Users/username/Documents/Dropbox/site2/public/
     <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Site 1 works as it should but Site 2 does not. So I ran a test. In each of the .htaccess files I did an environment check.

```
SetEnv HTACCESS on
```

Then I made a PHP file in the the root with this check.

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTACCESS']);
```

My output for site 1 is: `string(2) "on"`
My output for site 2 is: `null`

On both sites if I just go to /index.php they work correctly. Any clue what I can do for troubleshooting from here?  File permissions?

Comment: Permissions?  Can the user that's running apache access the directory and has read permissions on the .htaccess file for site2?

Comment: The file permissions, owner, and group are the same on both the directory and .htaccess file.

Comment: yes - and don't forget about the extended Posix ACLs that OS X uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have stumbled onto the answer accidently.  I was looking in different folder in /etc/apache2/ and found saw a directory called users. In there was a .conf file with my username. In there it had just one  that had AllowOverride set to None.  This conf file must have been overriding the vhost.  I set it to all and it seems to work fine now.